# EmberJS IP address TextField Mask

Tags: ember.js

Does anyone know of a relatively easy way to mask a TextField in emberjs to only accept valid ip addresses?

I found this: http://mlntn.com/2009/12/30/jquery-ip-address-plugin/, but it doesn't seem to work well with the way ember handles data. I believe this plugin assigns the ip to the value of the input field, rather than working with ember's data binding.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you had a look at this: https://github.com/guilhermeaiolfi/emberjs-maskinput